# Conv1D(filters=N, kernel_size=K) versus Dense(output_dim=N) layer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, convolution

I have an input tensor T of size `[batch_size=B, sequence_length=L, dim=K]`. Is applying a 1D convolution of N filters and kernel size K the same as applying a dense layer with output dimension of N?

For example in Keras:

```
Conv1D(filters=N, kernel_size=K)
```

vs

```
Dense(units=N)
```

Note for `Conv1D`, I reshape the tensor T to `[batch_size*sequence_length, dim=K, 1]` to perform the convolution.

Both result in learnable weights of 20,480 + 256 (bias). Yet using `Conv1D` learns much faster initially for me. I don't see how `Dense()` is any different in this case and I'd like to use `Dense()` method in order have the lower vram consumption as well as not reshape tensor.

---

Follow up clarification:

The two answers provided two different ways to perform the 1D convolution. How are the following methods different?:

Method 1:

```
- Reshape input to [batch_size * frames, frame_len]
- convolve with Conv1D(filters=num_basis, kernel_size=frame_len)
- Reshape the output of the convolution layer to [batch_size, frames, num_basis]
```

Method 2:

```
- Convolve with Conv1D(filters=num_basis, kernel_size=1) on Input=[batch_size, frames, frame_len]. No input reshaping.
- No need to reshape output, it's already [batch_size, frames, num_basis]
```

My understanding is that it's the same operation (they have the same #parameters). However, I'm getting faster convergence with method 1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To achieve the same behaviour as a Dense layer using a Conv1d layer, you need to make sure that any output neuron from the Conv1d is connected to every input neuron.

For an input of size [batch_size, L, K], your Conv1d needs to have a kernel of size L and as many filters as you want outputs neurons. To understand why, let's go back to the definition of a 1d convolution or temporal convolution.

The Conv1d layer’s parameters consist of a set of learnable filters. Every filter is usually small temporally and extends through the full depth of the input volume. For example, in your problem, a typical filter might have size 5xK (i.e. 5 steps of your sequence, and K because your input have depth K). During the forward pass, we slide (more precisely, convolve) each filter across the different steps of the input volume's sequence and compute dot products between the entries of the filter and the input at any position. As we slide the filter, we will produce a 1-dimensional activation map that gives the responses of that filter at every spatial position.

Now, if your filters are of size LxK, you can easily see that you will have only one possible spatial position (as the filter is the same size as the sequence) that will be the dot product between the full input volume and the weights LxK for each filter. The different filters composing your Conv1d now behave the same as the units composing a Dense layer: they are fully connected to your input.

You can verify this behaviour with the following code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

l = 10
k = 2
n = 5

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, l, k])
c = tf.layers.conv1d(inputs=x, strides=1, filters=n, kernel_size=l, kernel_initializer=tf.ones_initializer())
d = tf.layers.dense(inputs=tf.reshape(x, [-1, l*k]), units=n, kernel_initializer=tf.ones_initializer())

batch_size = 10

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    r_conv, r_dense = sess.run([c, d], {x: np.random.normal(size=[batch_size, l, k])})

print(r_conv.shape, r_dense.shape)
#(10, 1, 5) (10, 5)

print(np.allclose(r_conv.reshape([batch_size, -1]), r_dense.reshape([batch_size, -1])))
#True
```

For the same initialization, the outputs are indeed equal.

Regarding speed, I suppose that one of the main reason the Conv1d was faster and took more VRAM was because of your reshape: you were virtually increasing your batch size, improving parallelization at the cost of memory.

---

**Edit after follow up clarification:**

Maybe I misunderstood your question. Method 1 and Method 2 are the same but they are not the same as applying a Dense layer to the Input=[B, LxK].

Here, your outputs are connected to the full dimension K and then the same weights are used for every time step of your sequence meaning that both method are only fully connected to the frame but not the sequence. This is equivalent to a Dense layer on [BxL, K] indeed.

You can verify this behaviour with the following code:

```
l = 10
k = 2
n = 5

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, l, k])
c2 = tf.layers.conv1d(inputs=x, strides=1, filters=n, kernel_size=1, kernel_initializer=tf.ones_initializer())
c3 = tf.layers.conv1d(inputs=tf.reshape(x, [-1, k, 1]), strides=1, filters=n, kernel_size=k, kernel_initializer=tf.ones_initializer())
d2 = tf.layers.dense(inputs=tf.reshape(x, [-1, k]), units=n, kernel_initializer=tf.ones_initializer())

batch_size = 10

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    r_d2, r_c2, r_c3 = sess.run([d2, c2, c3], {x: np.random.normal(size=[batch_size, l, k])})
    r_d2 = r_d2.reshape([10, 10, 5])
    r_c3 = r_c3.reshape([10, 10, 5])

print(r_d2.shape, r_c2.shape, r_c3.shape)
#(10, 10, 5) (10, 10, 5) (10, 10, 5)

print(np.allclose(r_d2, r_c2))
#True
print(np.allclose(r_d2, r_c3))
#True
print(np.allclose(r_c2, r_c3))
#True
```

Concerning the speed, it must be because there is only one dot product in Method 1 to compute the result whereas you have L in Method 2 + other operations.

Comment: Could you please take a look at the follow up question I've edited. I don't see how your method is different from the only recommended by Daniel's answer. Yet the two behave differently for me.

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! For `c3` convolution, why do you have `strides=k`? From my testing, the stride value is ignored for that convolution. Is it sliding on the first dimension (`batch_size * l`) with a stride of 1?

Comment: It was a mistake when I changed the values. It doesn't change the results though as there is only one possible position so the stride value is indeed ignored. Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 3):

There are two cases where the operations for Conv1D and Dense have the same results:

1. For 3D inputs with shape `(batch, length, channels)`, these two are the same:

   - `Conv1D(filters=N, kernel_size =1)`
   - `Dense(units=N)`

This uses a `Dense` layer to simulate a convolution with `kernel_size=1`.
Greater kernel sizes (`kernel_size > 1`) cannot be achieved by `Dense` this way.

2. For Conv1D with inputs like `(batch, length, features)` and Dense with inputs like `(batch, length * features)`, these two are the same:

   - `Conv1D(filters=N, kernel_size=length, padding='valid')`
   - `Dense(units=N)`

This uses a `Conv1D` layer to simulate a fully connected layer.
Notice that although both layers may have the same number of parameters, a convolution is a totally different operation. If you change the padding you will be performing much more multiplications in Conv1D, having a different output.

About the speed, `Dense` and `Conv1D` are different algorithms, although their result will be the same in the two cases above. Different algorithms are implemented differently, so don't expect the exact same speed.

Comment: Did you mean `Conv1D(filters = N, kernel_size = L)` ? If not, your statement is false.  Also, I don't really know what you mean by "Greater kernel sizes cannot be achieved by Dense.". At the contrary, a dense layer is by definition the biggest kernel as it is connected to the whole input.

Comment: Dense layers do not perform convolutions at all. My statement is not false. But I added a second case I hadn't realized before. You can simulate `kernel size = 1` like I mentioned with Dense. Or you can simulate `kernel_size = L` as long as you understand the input shapes are different.

Comment: I was just saying that if you want to do a parallel between the two in tems of kernels (as you did), then a Dense layer would be a convolution with the biggest possible kernel as it is connected to the whole input. Also, if you think in term of code, yes your statement holds true. But, while `Dense([B, L, K], N)` will run, it is different from a Dense/FC layer stricto sensu since every output neuron is not connected to the whole input but only the K dimension. The "Dense" layer is very sparse in this setting...

Comment: I see... the thing is that I was talking about "simulating a convolution with a dense layer" (case 1), instead of "simulating a dense layer with a convolution" (case 2).